# reading a table/data frame into R that has both x and y axis labels

Tags: r, csv

I'm very new to R, and I don't know if this is actually even possible. I've been using read.csv() to read a table into R that is comma separated.

I keep getting this error message that is telling me: "more column than column names"

I believe that the issue involves the fact that my files have both x and y axis labels.

So they look something like this:

> ,y1,y2,y3,
>
> x1,data,data,data,
>
> x2,data,data,data,
>
> x3,data,data,data,

The y and x are different labels depending on the actual file, but its just as a demonstration.

Is there any way to read this into R? Or do I have to remove the x axis labels for all files...

Thanks

Comment: The row names and column names of a data set cannot all be identical, so I think you may need to make the header and row names into their own row or column.

Comment: the row names and column names aren't identical. they are all different. The above is just an example of the format, but all individual labels are different

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because R sees four columns, and only three column names.

The argument `row.names = 1` will tell R that the first column of the file is actually the vector of row names, and it will apply them accordingly.

```
> read.csv(text = ",y1,y2,y3,
  x1,data,data,data,
  x2,data,data,data,
  x3,data,data,data,", row.names = 1)[-4]
## results in
##      y1   y2   y3
## x1 data data data
## x2 data data data
## x3 data data data
```

The `[-4]` removes the `NA` column that gets added using this process (due to the extra comma in the column names, I think).  It could differ in your complete data set (try it without to see).

So, what I would suggest you do is

```
read.csv("yourFile.csv", row.names = 1)
```

and then remove the last column.